# how do i run an excecutable file for r from github

Tags: r, github

I know this is an extremely basic question, but someone suggested i try running [a code](https://github.com/amignan/risk_eq_mmax/blob/master/get_mmax.R) from github and I have no idea how to go about it

I tried copying and pasting but that didn't work and neither does downloading it and trying to open it with R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the raw button on github to get the url

`source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amignan/risk_eq_mmax/master/get_mmax.R")`